# SPA product Cart

Tags: single-page-application, cart

I need to create a product cart using the SPA application. My question is more about architecture.
Where should I store product data in the cart?
I see 2 options for solving this issue:
Store data on the client (Local Storage, or redux state)
There is a problem. If i'll use the local storage, then it is likely that the data will be accessible to different users working from the same device, or i need to delete the cart data during authentication. Then the data will not be accessible to the one user between different login sessions
With redux this is the same situation
If i'll store cart data at the data base - each user’s sneeze, such as adding goods, deleting, changing the quantity, will be accompanied by API requests and synchronization

I do not need specific examples of React or Angular, just tell me the principle of solution. What are the best practices?